# Why my emulator is showing this graphic glitches, earlier it was working fine

Tags: android, graphics, android-emulator, nvidia

This is the first time I had encounter this graphic issue while using the android emulator, I was having nvidea graphics card issues earlier but it has no effects on my emulator earlier but now I am facing this issues how to handle this, though I have selected Automatic option of graphics rendering of Emulated performance

This is the screenshot of my emulator

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Emulator try to use Hardware Acceleration of your Video Card, and this is a typical glitch of corrupted driver or hardware. Here are a few possibilities:

1. Android Emulator has a broken file when it load the display drivers it somehow fails
2. your Windows/Linux video drivers are corrupted
3. your video card is near to die and cannot well process Hardware Acceleration (for this last case: does the glitch involves some other softwares like 3D gaming?)

Comment: Yes, the glitch is there on Unity software and even on Asphalt game what will we the possible solution.

Comment: Try to run a GAME on your main Operating System, not inside the Emulator. This test will show if the error is only INSIDE the emulator or even in your Main OS.

Comment: Yes tried even on main Operating System but same issues

Comment: You can try to update your Video Card Drivers, but it could not solve the problem if it is an Hardware problem. If the update doesn't solve it than you have a Video Card near to death.